# Apply $match-filter on mongo aggregate result

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have created a small mongo aggregation pipeline, which I write and run from PHP.

The aggregation method looks like this:

```
$results = $mongoCollection->aggregate([
    ['$group' => ['_id' => ['FoobarID' => '$FoobarID'], 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]],
    ['$match' => ['count' => ['$gte' => 10]]],
    ['$sort' => ['count' => -1]]
]);
```

The (first few) records of the result looks like that:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [_id] => Array
            (
                [FoobarID] => 0
            )
        [count] => 836
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [_id] => Array
            (
                [FoobarID] => MongoInt64 Object
                    (
                        [value] => 967298418588464438
                    )
            )
        [count] => 105
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [_id] => Array
            (
                [FoobarID] => MongoInt64 Object
                    (
                        [value] => 3397585370383372261
                    )
            )
        [count] => 101
    )

...
```

**Question 1**

Now I am trying to remove first aggregation result, the one having FoobarID = 0. I am unable to get this to work.

As you can see, the $match on "count" works, but I am unable to filter the FoobarID field in the result.

I have tried the following:

```
['$match' => ['_id' => ['$ne' => 0]]], // also tried '0' and null

['$match' => ['FoobarID' => ['$ne' => 0]]], // also tried '0' and null

['$match' => ['_id' => ['FoobarID' => ['$ne' => 0]]]], // also tried '0' and null
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

**Question 2**

How can I access the 'value'-keys inside the MongoInt64 Object? Is that possible at all? E.g. remove the aggregation result with FoobarID MongoInt64 Value = 967298418588464438?

Any comments and help is really appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1

Try this.

```
['$match' => ['_id.FoobarID' => ['$ne' => 0]]]
```

Question 2

```
['$match' => ['_id.FoobarID' => ['$eq' => 967298418588464438]]]
```

Comment: Veeram: Thank you very much! Your answer for question 1 solves the problem perfectly! :-) I had no success with the second one, though. I also tried different slighty changes versions with "_id.FoobarID.value" and the number als int and as string...

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not really well versed with php to give you good answer. So can you tell me what id is that. is that a `objectId` ?

Comment: No, it is not an objectId. It is a proprietary ID, from type "MongoInt64 Object". So it is not a 32-bit integer, it is a 64-bit integer.

Comment: You are on 64 bit php driver correct ? so it should just be a normal comparison